# Excel - I'd like to know how to have my data validation drop down select a client and then show this person's properties in the following cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to correctly map my data. Have clients and their properties, then in another sheet, have a drop down showing the clients. Once you select a client, is like excel to show his properties, in their own cells. Please help.

Comment: How much work have you done so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Use standard Data Validation to select the client from a list of clients and then use *VLOOKUP()* or *MATCH()/INDEX()* to retrieve associated data.